# SendGrid Apex attachment functionality is not working?

Tags: apex, email, attachment

I am using Send Grid Apex package for sending out bulk email from salesforce.It's possible to send text files as a attachment with the help of Send Grid API.But it failed for every other type of files ( like pdf etc).

Is there any workaround for this problem. I have tried calling web API of sendgrid for attachments from Apex code with the help of callouts . Its not working for pdf and other files .

can someone please help me ?

API doc : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue this week. To send attachments other than .txt you need to send them as multipart/form-data. There is an example [**here**](https://github.com/Kaptio/SalesforceToSendgridWithAttachmentsExample/blob/master/example.cls). I have used this approach just now and can confirm that it works fine, there is also x-smtpapi header available where you can use all that filters, substitutions and other nice things available in the package that you've referenced.

Here is the code from referenced example:

```
public with sharing class TestSendGridWithAttachments {

    public static void sendRequestToSendGrid(){

        List<Document> dd = [SELECT
            Id, Body, Name, BodyLength
            FROM Document
            WHERE DeveloperName IN ('testimage1', 'testpdf1') // change to yours document
        ];

        String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';

        String header = '';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_user"\r\n\r\nYOUR_LOGIN\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_key"\r\n\r\nYOUR_PASSWORD\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"\r\n\r\nYOUR_EMAIL\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"\r\n\r\nFROM_EMAIL\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fromname"\r\n\r\nSENDER_NAME\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"\r\n\r\nSUBJECT\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"\r\n\r\nTEXT_BODY\r\n';
        header += '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
        header += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="html"\r\n\r\nHTML_BODY\r\n';

        String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';

        String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
        while(headerEncoded.endsWith('=')) {
            header += ' ';
            headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
        }

        String attachmentsStr = '';
        String lastPrepend = '';
        if (dd.size() > 0) {
            for (Document d : dd) {
                Blob fileBlob = d.Body;
                String filename = d.Name;
                String fHeader = lastPrepend + '--'+boundary+'\r\n';
                fHeader += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files['+filename+']"; filename="'+filename+'"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';
                String fHeaderEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(fheader+'\r\n\r\n'));
                while(fHeaderEncoded.endsWith('=')) {
                    fHeader += ' ';
                    fHeaderEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(fHeader+'\r\n\r\n'));
                }
                String fbodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(fileBlob);
                String last4Bytes = fbodyEncoded.substring(fbodyEncoded.length()-4,fbodyEncoded.length());
                if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
                    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
                    fBodyEncoded = fbodyEncoded.substring(0,fbodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
                    lastPrepend = '';
                } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
                    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
                    fBodyEncoded = fbodyEncoded.substring(0,fbodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
                    lastPrepend = '\n';
                } else {
                    lastPrepend = '\r\n';
                }
                attachmentsStr += fHeaderEncoded + fBodyEncoded;
            }
            footer = lastPrepend + footer;
        } else {
            footer = '\r\n' + footer;
        }

        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        Blob bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+attachmentsStr+footerEncoded);
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json');
        req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    }


}
```